# SHA-1 For Image Filenames, Still Safe?

Tags: rest, encryption, sha

I've heard to never use SHA-1 anymore, but I don't have a lot of the context around this.

Is okay to use SHA-1 to obfuscate user-uploaded image filenames being returned from my REST service? They do not need to be unique.

Or should they just straight up not be used for anything?

Comment: what it randomization for you? How do you randomize with a hash function?

Comment: Explain "randomized image filenames" please.

Comment: @PresidentJamesMoveonPolk sorry, I mean obfuscating the filenames for user-uploaded images.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**SHA-1** is a [hashing algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) which takes a string and hashes it. There are ways out there to reverse this hash, which is why it should never be used for passwords or other sensitive data.

As for file names, it would be fine to use **SHA-1** for them but the resulting hash would be predicated on the string that you are hashing and has no guarantee of being unique (if you want uniqueness).

Comment: I'm not aware there are any ways to reverse the sha-1. Could you refer to any? As far I know there are ways to create content resulting to the same hash (not necessary the same content)

Comment: In theory it's possible. There's a lot of conflicting evidence about it being possible and not being possible, but that, in and of itself, it enough to make me say it's not suitable for sensitive information (not what the OP is looking for but worth mentioning)

Comment: @CarlMarkham Yeah, I'm not looking for anything secure– just hashing an image to obfuscate the original filename (I'm also stripping the image metadata). Is it okay to use SHA-1 for this? It's not for sensitive data.

Comment: @aroooo in that case - it is safe to use sha-1 like to obfuscane / anonymize data. Please note - a cryptographic hash is designed to be collision resistance, it means there is a very low probability you will get the same hash result for different file names, but mathematically it is not zero. For common use cases you can consider the probability negligible, but for audited processes (health, government, bank records, ..) you should handle these cases